# Vue Router in Vue.js 3.0 problem with redirecting named page to other named page

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

this is propably basic question to ask but i have a problem with router settings. I have managed to build a nice, clean Views inside CMS system i am working on and my router settings looks like

```js
const routes = [{
  path: "/cms/dashboard/",
  redirect: "/cms/dashboard/summary/"
}, {
  path: "/cms",
  name: "CMS",
  component: CMS,
  children: [{
    id: ":id",
    path: ":viewSlug",
    name: "cmsView",
    props: true,
    component: () => import( /*webpackChunkName: "dashboard" */ "../views/CMS/CmsView.vue"),
    children: [{
      id: ":id",
      path: ":childSlug",
      name: "nestedRoute",
      props: true,
      component: () => import( /*webpackChunkName: "dashboard" */ "../views/CMS/NestedView.vue"),
      children: [{
        id: ":id",
        path: ":secondChildSlug",
        name: "nestedSecond",
        props: true,
        component: () => import( /*webpackChunkName: "dashboard" */ "../views/CMS/SecondNestedView.vue"),
      }]
    }]
  }],
}];
```

so as you can see i am basically using only named routes which is neat because i can design all the pages i want in CMS to be just .json files that are included in store. The problem is redirecting seems not to work properly. The code:

```js
{
  path: "/cms/dashboard/",
  redirect: "/cms/dashboard/summary/"
}
```

Works only when i refresh the page - so when I refresh a page when i am under /cms/dashboard - redirect works just fine, but when i go to "/cms/dashboard" via navigation - nothing happens. That's a little bit frustrating because i just want to always show child component as well as main component in every view.

Comment: Shout in the dark but should `path` not have a trailing slash in `/cms/dashboard/`?

Comment: I tried almost every configuration - with and without and even only using /dashboard to /dashboard/summary etc. I belive i am missing something because this configuration i have seems to work on refresh but not when i go through a link. Maybe named is there a possibility that named routes cannot be redirected as such? If so i would prepare router with all the paths i need and than use just the same component but i need to know if there is some simpler solution to why is this not working.

Comment: Another shot in the dark, but try adding `:key="$route.fullPath"` to your `<router-view>` element(s) to force rerendering components on URL change

Comment: Well it still doesn't work. I wrote beforeCreate and beforeUpdate methods to watch wether the viewslug contains "dashboard" in it. It works perfectly still don't know why is that happening tough.